# Best practices for a photo app with react native + firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, image-processing, google-cloud-storage

I'm using React Native to build an instagram-like application, with a firebase backend. The Firebase storage to which I save my images returns an `https` link that I use to put as the `source` in my `Image` components. Even rendering the same image on a different page causes a new http network call. I'm realizing pretty quickly that an app that has to constantly make all these http calls would have some drawbacks. Instagram seems to have a seamless flow of images once they are initially rendered.

I was thinking of making a single call to all the relevant images, converting each url into a `base64` encoding, and using that as the `source` to the `Image` components for a much faster local rendering, and very little network usage. I could even use the expo file system for that to cache images? The downside I see is that this would slow down the user device by using too much local memory.

I'm not very familiar with native, this is my first app, so not sure if storing 100s of base64 images locally is a good idea, but I feel like constantly hitting the same URLs is redundant.

I'm sure this has been addressed before, but what is the most ideal way of handling this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using react native but I am using react + firestore.
I would create a posts collection, each post document has a map or array of image urls (image maps if you need extra info). You could also do a sub collection for images but I'm not sure what restraints work for your project. Each post doc would also have a user uid and a created timestamp.

I would assume a simple `posts.where("userId", "===", THIS_USER_ID).orderBy("created", "desc")` query would suffice for a user profile. After that you would need to cache images to avoid requesting again on a new page render.

You would need to find an efficient way for mapping out follower pairs. Once you have that you just grab all user photos and sort by created in descending order again for a user feed.

Answer (score 0):

Update, I actually went with the `react-query` package to handle client side cacheing of server-state. Works really well, data is held until a forced invalidation (i.e: pull down to refresh) or cache expiry.